# How to protect low-voltage hardwired device against 120 V AC miswiring ? (I need a resettable solution)

Tags: circuit-protection, ac-dc, surge-protection, low-voltage

I need to protect a hardwired device, made for AC low-voltage transformers (e.g.  doorbell), from miswiring to a 120 V AC power line. It actually occurs no matter how many warnings I put everywhere.

The space for the circuit is small (must be slim 8 mm x 9 mm, but can be long e.g. 40 mm). The device is between 4 W and 8 W depending on the configuration. The maximum acceptable voltage drop is 2 V.

All solutions I found have at least one of these problems:

- Large parts (it must be compact)
- Overheats (must be kept under 125 °C)
- Works only with lower voltages i.e. protects 5 V input from 9 V

I think of first passing the input voltage through a full bridge rectifier, to deal with positive voltage only. But at 170-180 V, I can't figure out how a small MOSFET or BJT can make that possible.

Any ideas, or help please?

Comment: This feels more like a user issue than a design issue. I think the appropriate way to solve this would be to tackle why people keep wiring it to 120 V AC instead of what it's meant to be wired to. For example, if people are ignoring the warnings on the packaging, put a warning over the wires themselves, so that they can't be wired in without physically removing the warning label. Or, if it's feasible, sell the device with the transformer included (practical if your device is expensive, not so much otherwise).

Comment: Thank you for your help. The label is actually over the wire almost over the contacts. At the end, the problem still there and the customer always win.

Comment: What is the current draw of your low voltage device? How much voltage loss can you tolerate for your low voltage device?

Comment: A simple solution which is somewhat wasteful of power and space, and a little bit slow, is a normally closed relay, with a 110VAC coil, with its coil across the power supply, and it's contacts separating the power supply and the load. When mains power is applied, the relay opens, disconnecting the supply from the load. The same could be accomplished by emulating such a relay with solid state electronics. For example, a normally closed solid state relay with a zener and resistor pair for the input, or a more complex transistor circuit to accomplish the same as an SS Relay.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a sizeable diode between GND a V+ with some sort of reset fuse.

This will short the input on the AC negative wave and trip the fuse fast.

The tricky part is to protect the electronics behind for 20ms at 120V (50Hz). A big 120V cap with a 100ohm serial resistor (if you can accept the voltage drop) and a resettable fuse might do it. Some LDO that can take high transients can help.

Some ideas:

[image: schematic]

Add discharge resistor on the cap.

It would need to be tested and the components adjusted depending on your circuit.

Comment: Resettable PTC fuse already has resistance. TVS diode protect from negative polarity. It is zenner diode. Also it designed to absorb big current in short time. No needs for capacitor.

Comment: If I understand the schematics, the reset fuse will trig at any AC voltage, but my circuit is made for AC low-voltage from 12 V to 24 V.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that point @Oaristys, Is the transformer supplied by you? which in that case you could add a bridge rectifier. Does your circuit work in AC or DC?

Comment: The circuit is DC, but I need to make it compatible with DC source from 12 V to 24 V, and with AC sources from 12 V (ideally 8 V) to 24 V. And i need it AC 120 V safe, but again, ideally, directly compatible with AC 120 V.

Comment: One way is to have a 2 position switch on the device like many has for 230 / 110V